# How to create a 2D array in ROS

Tags: ros, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to do a custom msg as 2D array which has 4 variables. x, y, velocity, and angle. Each variable will be set to a value as 2D array. Below is the code:

```
matlab_file_dic = scipy.io.loadmat(map_file)
map_data_values = matlab_file_dic['mapData'][0][0][2]
map_data =  np.reshape(map_data_values,(1000,9), 'F')

for k in range(9):
    for i in range(1000):
        par_name = 'Parameters.mapData.FunctionValues[{}]'.format(k*1000 + i)
        self.model.set(par_name, map_data[i, k])

self.model.set('Parameters_INI_VALUES_COURSE_ANGLE', map_data[start_sim, 2])
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406423/how-to-create-a-2d-array-in-ros/) by [m0gha](https://answers.ros.org/users/114445/m0gha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-14**:
The question is hard to understand. Do you want to create a custom message? Furthermore, I could not understand the relation of your code snippet with the title of your question. Can you please provide more information?

**Comment by [m0gha](https://answers.ros.org/users/114445/m0gha/) on 2022-09-18**:
I want to create a custom message, the message should be a 2D array " map_data[i, k] "

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-09-19**:
Just to make it *extra clear*: there is no such thing as an "Nd array" (with `N > 1`) in ROS msg IDL. It's not supported.

The best you can do is use one of the work-arounds suggested/described by @ravijoshi in his answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following two approaches can be utilized in order to create a custom message that contains a 2D array, (`map_data` in your case):

1. **Using nested .msg:** In this approach, you define two .msg files as shown below:

   1. Create `Row.msg` file with the following content:

      ```
       int8[] data
      ```

      - Here, you create a row of your map.
      - Please note that, I am assuming that map contains data of type `int8`. Please change it as per your need.
   2. Create `Map.msg` file with the following content:

      ```
       Row[] row
      ```

      - Here, you append the above created row to your msg.
      - Please check the following link for more info. #q67273
2. **Using flattened array:** In this approach, you reshape your 2D array to make it a 1D array. This is the simplest approach and used by ROS to publish images (2D data). You are free to check the message definition of [sensor_msgs/Image](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) and read more about it.

## Example

Consider you have the following 2D array:

```
In [1]: map_data
Out[1]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]], dtype=int8)
```

1. **Approach #1:** Create every row and append it to map as shown below:

   ```
    # initialize map
    map = Map()

    # initialize row with 1D data
    row1 = Row([ 0,  1,  2,  3])

    # append row to map
    map.row.append(row1)

    row2 = Row([ 4,  5,  6,  7])
    map.row.append(row2)
    row3 = Row([ 8,  9, 10, 11])
    map.row.append(row3)
   1. NumPy Simulation:

        In [2]: row1 = np.array([ 0,  1,  2,  3])
        In [3]: row2 = np.array([ 4,  5,  6,  7])
        In [4]: row3 = np.array([ 8,  9, 10, 11])

        In [5]: map_data_received = np.vstack((row1, row2, row3))
        In [6]: map_data_received
        Out[6]: 
        array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
               [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
               [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
   ```
2. **Approach #2:** Just flatten your data and publish it. Upon subscribing, reshape it back to 2D as shown in the NumPy simulation below:

   ```
    In [6]: map_data.flatten()
    Out[6]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])

    In [7]: map_data_received = map_data.flatten().reshape((3,-1))
    In [8]: map_data_received
    Out[8]: 
    array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
   ```

---

On a side note, it seems that your variable `map_data_values` is already a 1D array. So, approach #2 can be applied directly.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [m0gha](https://answers.ros.org/users/114445/m0gha/) on 2022-09-20**:
Thanks so much. It works :)

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-20**:
Glad you made it work. Please upvote the answer and accept it by clicking on mark this answer correct.